# Design a custom qweb report in Landscape format

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I want to design a custom qweb report in Landscape format.I want to do that from backend.Lets assume `test_module` is my module name.
I tried like this :

```
<report
    id="report_sale_order_landscape_id"
    model="sale.order"
    string="Sale Order Landscape"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="sale.report_sale_order_landscape"
    file="sale.report_sale_order_landscape"
/>

<record id="paperformat_sale_order_landscape" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="name">PF Sale Order Landscape</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True"/>
    <field name="format">A4</field>
    <field name="page_height">0</field>
    <field name="page_width">0</field>
    <field name="orientation">Landscape</field>
    <field name="margin_top">10</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">15</field>
    <field name="margin_left">7</field>
    <field name="margin_right">7</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
    <field name="header_spacing">3</field>
    <field name="dpi">90</field>
</record>
<record id="report_sale_order_landscape" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
  <field name="paperformat_id" ref="paperformat_sale_order_landscape" />
</record>
```

But I am facing some errors.
Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

> Error
>   [image: Log 1]

[image: Log 2]

[image: Log 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this may be help you

```
<record id="paperformat_sale_order_landscape" model="report.paperformat">
<field name="name">PF Sale Order Landscape</field>
<field name="default" eval="True"/>
<field name="format">A4</field>
<field name="page_height">0</field>
<field name="page_width">0</field>
<field name="orientation">Landscape</field>
<field name="margin_top">10</field>
<field name="margin_bottom">15</field>
<field name="margin_left">7</field>
<field name="margin_right">7</field>
<field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
<field name="header_spacing">3</field>
<field name="dpi">90</field>
```

```
<report
id="report_sale_order_landscape_id"
model="sale.order"
string="Sale Order Landscape"
report_type="qweb-pdf"
name="sale.report_sale_order_landscape"
file="sale.report_sale_order_landscape"
paperformat="paperformat_sale_order_landscape"
```

/>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
<record id="report_sale_order_landscape" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="paperformat_sale_order_landscape" />
</record>
```

You can add paperformat attribute inside report definition:

```
<report
    id="report_sale_order_landscape_id"
    model="sale.order"
    string="Sale Order Landscape"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="sale.report_sale_order_landscape"
    file="sale.report_sale_order_landscape"
    paperformat="test_module.report_sale_order_landscape"
/>
```